# ¿Fueron comunes en algún momento los símbolos (como "km") con plurales volados?

Tags: ortografía, historia, plurales, símbolos

Volviendo a Sevilla desde Mérida por la carretera nacional, poco antes de llegar a Santiponce se puede ver una casa bastante vieja con un cartel igual de viejo, en el que se puede leer [lo siguiente](https://www.google.es/maps/@37.4868188,-6.0686291,3a,75y,124.97h,85.38t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-Knwdz026jty0WWSrlkOmQ!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo1.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D-Knwdz026jty0WWSrlkOmQ%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D147.19621%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656?hl=es):

[image: Plural volado]

> SANTIPONCE 6 Km<sup>s</sup>
>   SEVILLA 15 Km<sup>s</sup>

Hoy en día la *Ortografía* dice lo siguiente:

> Los símbolos no varían de forma aunque se usen en contextos de referencia plural: *25 km* por *veinticinco kilómetros* [...].

Pero claro, como este cartel es muy antiguo no se le pueden aplicar las reglas de ortografía actuales. Por tanto, la pregunta adquiere un corte histórico y trata los siguientes aspectos:

- ¿Fue de uso recomendado en algún momento por la RAE el escribir los símbolos (de unidades de medida) con plurales volados? ¿O, ya puestos, con plurales de cualquier tipo?
- ¿Acaso se consideraba el símbolo "km" una abreviatura antiguamente, y por eso se le aplicó algún tipo de regla similar a cuando se escribe, por ejemplo, "H<sup>nos</sup>"?
- Bonus: ¿El prefijo "kilo-" se escribió alguna vez con mayúscula?

Comment: Claramente el estado de la casa sugiere un uso antiguo :) Qué buena la pregunta y que pienses en este sitio cuando estás en la carretera jeje

Comment: @fedorqui [ese es mi secreto](https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tumblr_m835m1wVOX1qk04hlo2_500.gif)... siempre pienso en este sitio... (lo difícil en realidad es que al llegar a casa me acuerde de cuál era la pregunta que se me ocurrió).

Comment: @fedorqui necesitamos el blog de la mujer de Carlos para explicarnos mas detalles de la vida curiosa de Carlos.

Comment: @mdewey nunca pensé que mi vida le pudiera resultar de interés a alguien... :-D En todo caso lamento decirte que a mi mujer nunca le ha dado por escribir un blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¡Qué curioso! A mí también me suena haber visto ***Km.<sup>s</sup>*** en algún que otro letrero de la España profunda :D

Veamos...

En [este manual de física de 1854](https://books.google.es/books?id=jidbAAAAcAAJ&hl=es&pg=PA568#v=snippet&q=mil%C3%ADmetro&f=false), la gran mayoría de las unidades de medida aparecen escritas con la palabra completa: milímetro, litro, gramo... Sólo en contadas ocasiones se usan abreviaturas, y en ellas se distinguen dos casos:

- Cuando forman parte del texto, parecen abreviaturas normales: **kil.** por *kilogramos*, **kilóm.** por *kilómetros*, y así.
- Cuando indican las dimensiones en que se da una cantidad, se escriben como superíndice entre la parte entera y la decimal, así: **3<sup>mm</sup>,2** para *3,2 milímetros*. Algo parecido a como se sigue haciendo hoy día para las resistencias eléctricas.

Aunque parece que se abreviaban como palabras normales, no hay señal de que se usen plurales volados.

En [este otro manual de física de 1912](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&id=wYUMAQAAIAAJ&dq=f%C3%ADsica&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=km.), parece que ya se usan los símbolos que nos son familiares hoy: **mm.** por *milímetros*, **km.** por *kilómetros*, etc.; colocados a continuación del número y sin marcas de plural.
Sin embargo, aún hay [manuales posteriores](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&id=0dOEAAAAIAAJ&dq=f%C3%ADsica&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=kil.) que en 1920 siguen usando kil. para kilogramos y kilóm. para kilómetros.

En [un manual de 1942](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&id=JSRLAAAAMAAJ&dq=f%C3%ADsica&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=km.) aparece Km. con mayúscula, aunque se usa también km. en otras partes del libro.
En [otro de 1945](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&id=nnNTAAAAMAAJ&dq=ingenieria&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=km.) se usa exclusivamente km. y empiezan a aparecen los km<sup>2</sup>.

La casa de la foto no parece tener menos de 70 años, la verdad, así que voy a parar aquí.

De todo lo cual infiero: **no, lo habitual no era usar plurales volados con las unidades métricas**; si bien, es posible que algunas personas fuesen más creativas que otras a la hora de indicar dichas unidades de manera abreviada, durante el tiempo en el que no estaban establecidas las normas sobre su escritura (que no las fijó la RAE, sino [el CGPM en 1960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_metric_system)).