# ¿Por qué "kilómetro" es esdrújula, si "kilogramo" es llana?

Tags: acentuación

El título lo dice todo.

Es una duda que me ha surgido mientras investigaba la respuesta a [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21524/13628).

En realidad mi pregunta aplica a todas las unidades de medida en metros, que son todas esdrújulas, respecto de las demás en litros, gramos, vatios o lo que se quiera, que son llanas.

**Kilogramo** viene de kilo- y gramo. Gramo es llana, ergo "kilogramo".
**Kilómetro** viene de kilo- y metro. Metro es llana, ergo... ¿"kilometro"?

Idem para kilovatio, kilolitro, etc. así como para milivatio, centilitro, decagramo y cualquiera otra, respecto de milímetro, centímetro, decámetro y demás.

¿Por qué esa diferencia en la acentuación de palabras casi idénticas?

Comment: Referencia al artículo del DPD que menciona la respuesta de Gustavson: [_kilogramo_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=kilogramo)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Original tu pregunta. Aquí he encontrado la respuesta de la Academia Mexicana de la Lengua: https://es-es.facebook.com/ortografiaparatodos/posts/566961186709023

> La voz kilómetro tiene una acentuación esdrújula debido a que está formada por el elemento compositivo -metro, que es átono. Esta forma proviene del sustantivo metro y, al adquirir la condición de elemento compositivo, se vuelve átona. Cuando -metro se une a otro elemento, como kilo, el acento siempre recae en el primero: kilómetro, centímetro, decímetro, barómetro, termómetro, etc. En cambio, las otras formas por las que nos consulta están compuestas por las voces litro y gramo, que son sustantivos y que no se han convertido en elementos compositivos, por lo que tienen un acento propio que, en este caso, es llano o grave.
>   Cabe mencionar que, según el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, de la Real Academia Española y la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española (Bogotá: Santillana, 2005), la voz kilogramo es llana en todo el ámbito hispánico (pronunciación [kilográmo]), salvo en Chile, donde se usa con normalidad la forma esdrújula kilógramo, posiblemente por una analogía con la voz kilómetro:Una masa que aquí en la Tierra tiene un peso de 1 kilógramo, en la “superficie” del Sol pesaría 28.
>   Publicación original de Español de México.

Nota: A partir de los comentarios suscitados, podemos llegar a la conclusión de que, contrariamente a lo que ocurre con las palabras compuestas por “gramo” y “litro”, donde estos elementos compositivos no pierden carga semántica – y tampoco el acento – ante la adición de los elementos que se les anteponen (*kilo-, hecto-, deca-, deci-, centi-, mili-*), el componente “-metro” tiene la particularidad de formar palabras esdrújulas donde pierde el acento a favor de elementos semánticamente más ricos que lo anteceden (*taxímetro, caudalímetro, pluviómetro, frecuencímetro, espectrómetro, potenciómetro, amperímetro, velocímetro, magnetómetro, densímetro, gasómetro, odómetro* – abajo se adjunta una lista más completa) y la lengua parece hacer extensiva esta regla a los múltiplos y submúltiplos del metro (donde el componente “metro”, a pesar de no estar acentuado, tiene la misma jerarquía semántica que sus pares en los compuestos con “gramo” y “litro”).

[image]

Comment: @walen Seguramente son dos desarrollos separados. La palabra *metro* significa, etimológicamente, *medida*; y de ahí se han derivado el elemento compositivo *-metro*, por un lado (normalmente con significado de *instrumento de medida*), y la unidad de medida *metro* por otro. Luego, al formarse los múltiplos y submúltiplos del metro, se ha mantenido la acentuacion propia del elemento compositivo.

Comment: @walen ¿Qué necesidad habría de que "gramo" o "litro" sean elementos compositivos? *-metro*, al igual que *-meter* en inglés, forma palabras compuestas donde el componente en cuestión significa "medidor": termómetro, barómetro, pluviómetro. El significado de "gramo" y "litro" es más específico y por lo tanto la posibilidad de formar compuestos es al menos limitada (si no nula).